# How can I embed two fields together in serializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have model like:

```
class MyModel:
    somefield = ...
    ...
    f_value = ...
    f_metric = ...
```

The question is: How can I embed these fields in serializer: so that the resulting serialized object would look like this:

```
{
"somefield": ...,
...,
"f": {"value": ..., "metric": ...}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a nested serializer to make this work.

```
class FSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    value = serializers.Field(source="f_value")
    metric = serializers.Field(source="f_metric")

class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    somefield = serializers.Field()

    f = FSerializer(source="*")
```

This should give you the nested output you are looking for. You can find more information on nesting serializers in the Django REST Framework documentation.

Comment: It returns `AttributeError: Object has no attribute 'f'`.